# I can't update my spotify on 13.04, what should I do?

Tags: updates, 13.04, spotify

Please let me know what details I should provide for troubleshooting.

Comment: Any error messages? How do you update?

Comment: If the answer below solved your problem , please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get -f install; sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

**UPDATE**

You might need to add the spotify repos again:

```
sudo echo "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then run the commands at the top.

Comment: Please explain the command, what it does and how it works. Thanks!

Comment: First one checks for and fixes dependency issues. Second one installs spotify.